# facebook feed dialogue not opening in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using following code, the dialogue is showing up in my chrome but client and client's client chrome it is not while in IE and firefox it is showing up for them. Any information ?

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "<?=$config['appId'];?>", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: '#',
      link: 'https://www.facebook.com/MyPageName/app_<?=$config['appId'];?>',
      picture: 'https://www.abc.com/fbapp/img/welcome.jpg',
      to: friendId,// js variable I am fetching from radio button selection
      name: 'App Blah Blah',
      caption: 'your_caption',
      description: 'your_description'
    };

    function callback(response) {
// I commented out message print in div
//          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];

// check weither feedback is valid
        if(typeof(response)!='undefined'){
            document.location = 'thankyou.php';
        }
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used

```
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.
```

I replaced it with

```
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

And all are happy, it's visible on all browsers.